# iterate over apache 2 log file names and compare numbers using linux bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, apache

Here is an example of logs in my /var/www/apache2/log folder-

```
./no_domain_access.log.7.gz
./no_domain_access.log.8.gz
./no_domain_access.log.9.gz
./no_domain_error.log.10.gz
./no_domain_error.log.11.gz
./no_domain_error.log.12.gz
./no_domain_error.log.13.gz
./no_domain_error.log.14.gz
./no_domain_error.log.15.gz
./no_domain_error.log.16.gz
./no_domain_error.log.17.gz
./no_domain_error.log.18.gz
./no_domain_error.log.19.gz
./no_domain_error.log.20.gz
```

and goes until 50...

I would like to iterate over those files and remove all log files that are greater then 5.

using regex syntax will give me the option to match numbers in the pattern of  [1-9] or {1,2}  but this will also match that log files that i dont want to delete ( single numbers 1-5 log files that i wish to keep)

How can i match only file names with numbers higher than 5 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` one-liner for this:

```
printf '%s\n' *[0-9].gz | awk -F '.' '$(NF-1) >= 5'
```

This awk command uses dot as field separator and compared `$(NF-1)` (that is the numeric field before extension) with number `5`.

To delete these files use:

```
printf '%s\n' *[0-9].gz | awk -F '.' '$(NF-1) >= 5' | xargs rm
```

`xargs` takes input from `awk` and `rm` command just deletes those files.

Comment: That's great thanks alot but can you explain  a little bit ,  i'm not that familiar with awk  and xargs.

Comment: Sure, I have added it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `bash`, regex operator `~` to extract the number and *list* the file if the number was greater than `5`

```
for file in /var/www/apache2/log/*.gz; do 
    test -f "$file" || continue
    [[ $file =~ ^.*log\.([[:digit:]]+).*$ ]] && { (( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" > 5  )) && printf "%s\n" "$file"; } 
done
```

If you just want to *delete* the files, replace `printf "%s\n"` by just `rm`.

Answer (score 0):

Find with regular expressions

```
find . -regex './no_domain_access.log.*gz' ! -regex './no_domain_access.log.[1-5].gz'
```

Find all files matching no_domain... and then run another regular expression to attain all these results minus files with 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expressions, using shell globs and entirely native & portable POSIX shell code:

```
rm -f no_domain_access.log.[6-9].gz no_domain_access.log.[0-9][0-9].gz
```

It's easier in bash:

```
rm -f no_domain_access.log.{6..50}.gz
```

These are probably created with [logrotate](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate) or a similar [log rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_rotation) utility. 
You might want to just change its configuration to only store five logs.

If it's controlled by logrotate, you can find the documentation with [`man logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) and you'll probably find something like this:

```
/var/log/no_domain_access.log {
    rotate 50
    daily
}
```

Change the `50` to `5` and you're done.  You probably(?) still have to clean up the current old logs using one of the above commands.